# getStringArrayList(key) in android generating null result

Tags: android, android-activity, null

When I click on the submit button, the next is activity started but in text view it generates a null result on the following code.

I want to store user details into an ArrayList, that should be passed to another activity and be displayed individually or even as a group.

CLASS A

```
ArrayList<String> fieldText = new ArrayList<String>();
   Intent i1; Bundle bnd1;

btSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                i1 = new Intent(WidgetDemo1Activity.this, Welcome.class);

                getDetails();

                startActivityForResult(i1,0);




            }
        });

public void getDetails(){
        fieldText.add(0, etuname.getText().toString());
        fieldText.add(1, etpass.getText().toString());
        //i1.putExtra("uname", etuname.getText().toString());
        //i1.putExtra("pass", etpass.getText().toString());
        bnd1 = new Bundle();
        //----- adding values of different field to bundle----- 
        //bnd1.putString("uname", etuname.getText().toString());
        //bnd1.putString("pass", etpass.getText().toString());
        bnd1.putStringArrayList("data", fieldText);
        i1.putExtras(bnd1);

        }
```

CLASS B

```
tv1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
tv1.setText("Welcome "+ getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("uname"));
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 ArrayList<String> arry=new ArrayList<String>();
 arry= getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("data");
```

instead of

```
tv1.setText("Welcome "+ getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("uname"));
```

because you are passing `data` as a key from First Activity and extracting `uname` from Second Activity

---

**EDIT:**

you can also try as for extracting ArrayList in Second Activity :

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<String> fieldText = new ArrayList<String>();

if(bundle !=null)
{
  fieldText = bundle.getStringArrayList("data"); 
}
else
{

}
```

because you are passing `ArrayList` in `Bundle` instead of `Intent`

Answer (score 0):

The key you are using to lookup from bundle is different. Use something like below.

```
tv1.setText("Welcome "+ getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("data"));
```

Comment: that i already tried but getting both user name and password. i need only username

Comment: If you don;t want both,  bnd1.putStringArrayList("data",  etuname.getText().toString());

Comment: bnd1.putStringArrayList("data", fieldText); - i want to pass data as an array list through bundle and need to received an individual item in next activity

Comment: No, don't pass fieldText (unless you want both there), because it contains both username & password. Just pass username bnd1.putString("uname", etuname.getText().toString());

Answer (score 0):

Class A...................

```
ArrayList<String> fieldText = new ArrayList<String>();
   Intent i1; Bundle bnd1;

btSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                i1 = new Intent(WidgetDemo1Activity.this, Welcome.class);

                getDetails();

                startActivityForResult(i1,0);




            }
        });

public void getDetails(){
        fieldText.add(0, etuname.getText().toString());
        fieldText.add(1, etpass.getText().toString());
        //i1.putExtra("uname", etuname.getText().toString());
        //i1.putExtra("pass", etpass.getText().toString());
        bnd1 = new Bundle();
        //----- adding values of different field to bundle----- 
        //bnd1.putString("uname", etuname.getText().toString());
        //bnd1.putString("pass", etpass.getText().toString());
        bnd1.putStringArrayList("data", fieldText);
        i1.putExtras(bnd1);

        }
```

Class B..............

```
TextView tv1;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

        ArrayList<String> al= new ArrayList<String>();
        al = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("data");
        tv1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);

        tv1.setText("Welcome "+ al.get(0)); // get string at 0 index 


    }
```